# Which data type for latitude and longitude?

Tags: postgresql, types, latitude-longitude, postgis

I am newbie to PostgreSQL and PostGIS. I want to store latitude and longitude values in PostgreSQL 9.1.1  database table. I will calculate distance between two points, find nearer points by using this location values.

Which data type should I use for latitude and longitude?

Comment: If you're doing two points (2D lat/lon map) I'd use the Geometry data type.  If you need to introduce altitude or curvature of the earth in your distance calcs, Geography is where you want to go.

Comment: Did any of the answers below address your question? If so, I encourage you to select one as the answer :)

Answer (score 226):

You can use the data type [**`point`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html#idm46428712347808) - combines `(x,y)` which can be your lat / long. Occupies 16 bytes: 2 `float8` numbers internally.

Or make it two columns of type [**`float`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT) (= `float8` or `double precision`). 8 bytes each.
Or **`real`** (= `float4`) if additional precision is not needed. 4 bytes each.
Or even [**`numeric`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) if you need absolute precision. 2 bytes for each group of 4 digits, plus 3 - 8 bytes overhead.

Read the fine manual about [numeric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) and [geometric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html).

---

The [**`geometry`**](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry.html) and [**`geography`**](https://postgis.net/docs/geography.html) data types are provided by the additional module **PostGIS** and occupy *one* column in your table. Each occupies 32 bytes for a point. There is some additional overhead like an SRID in there. These types store (long/lat), not (lat/long).

Start reading the [PostGIS manual here](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_GeographyVSGeometry).

Comment: I would not recommend using the `float` datatype. It makes calculation with the coordinates very complicated. You should use PostGIS and the `geography` datatype for such calculations.

Comment: It really is a fine manual isn't it? A shining example in documentation.

Comment: Would it be faster to store long, lat, and geog over trying parse geog for the original long lat?

Comment: @Dan: Depends. Please ask a new *question* with details. You can always link to this one for context. Comments are not the place for new questions.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Although this feels like an absolute way to go, we should keep in mind that: 1) It will require an equality operator. 2) Some cloud database providers (Digitalocean, GCP...) will not allow you to create an equality operator since they will require superuser access.

Answer (score 69):

In PostGIS, for points with latitude and longitude there is geography datatype.

To add a column:

```
alter table your_table add column geog geography;
```

To insert data:

```
insert into your_table (geog) values ('SRID=4326;POINT(longitude latitude)');
```

4326 is Spatial Reference ID that says it's data in degrees longitude and latitude, same as in GPS. More about it: http://epsg.io/4326

Order is Longitude, Latitude - so if you plot it as the map, it is (x, y).

To find closest point you need first to create spatial index:

```
create index on your_table using gist (geog);
```

and then request, say, 5 closest to a given point:

```
select * 
from your_table 
order by geog <-> 'SRID=4326;POINT(lon lat)' 
limit 5;
```

Comment: Clarification the SRID 4326 wants latitude longitude in that order. But PostGIS's interpretation of  SRID 4326 wants longitude latitude in that order. 

Example is correct for PostGIS use.

https://postgis.net/2013/08/18/tip_lon_lat/

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY location <-> point '(-74.013, 40.711)' LIMIT 10;

here point first element is longitude and the second element is latitude

Answer (score 29):

I strongly advocate for [PostGis](http://postgis.net). It's specific for that kind of datatype and it has out of the box methods to calculate distance between points, among other GIS operations that you can find useful in the future

Answer (score 15):

If you do not need all the functionality PostGIS offers, Postgres (nowadays) offers an extension module called [earthdistance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/earthdistance.html). It uses the [`point`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-geometric.html) or [`cube`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/cube.html) data type depending on your accuracy needs for distance calculations.

You can then use the `earth_box()` function to – for example – query for points within a certain distance of a location.

Answer (score 10):

In PostGIS Geometry is preferred over Geography (round earth model) because the computations are much simpler therefore faster. It also has MANY more available functions but is less accurate over very long distances.

Import your CSV long and lat fields to `DECIMAL(10,6)` columns. 6 digits is 10cm precision, should be plenty for most use cases. Then cast your imported data to the correct SRID

The wrong way!

```
/* try what seems the obvious solution */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.test_geom_bad;
-- Big Ben, London
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.116773, 51.510357),4326) AS geom
INTO public.test_geom_bad;
```

The CORRECT way

```
/* add the necessary CAST to make it work */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.test_geom_correct;
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.116773, 51.510357),4326)::geometry(Geometry, 4326) AS geom
INTO public.test_geom_correct;
```

Verify SRID is not zero!

```
/* now observe the incorrect SRID 0 */
SELECT * FROM public.geometry_columns
WHERE f_table_name IN ('test_geom_bad','test_geom_correct');
```

Validate the order of your long lat parameter using a WKT viewer and

`SELECT ST_AsEWKT(geom) FROM public.test_geom_correct`

Then index it for best performance

```
CREATE INDEX idx_target_table_geom_gist
    ON target_table USING gist(geom);
```

Comment: "less accurate over very long distances."  Could you mention what you mean by 'long distance'.  I've read this on many blogs but without an actual range of what is considered a long distance, I'm having a hard time figuring out which to use.

Comment: @GCQ I propose the optimal approach here would be for you to take some samples of your geo data and measure distances for yourself using Geometry once and Geography next and compare the outcomes. This is because accuracy of the coordinate reference systems (projections) varies geographically.

Comment: `select st_point(12.0, 42.0)::geometry(Geometry, 4326)` gives ERROR: Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326), but `select ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(12.0, 42.0),4326)` works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @mathieu thanks for pointing that out. I have both corrected and improved the answer to better highlight the risk of incorrectly setting the SRID.

Answer (score 4):

Use **Point** data type to store Longitude and Latitude in a single column:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    location point NOT NULL,
    created_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT table_name_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Create an Indexing on a 'location' column :

```
CREATE INDEX ON table_name USING GIST(location);
```

GiST index is capable of optimizing “nearest-neighbor” search :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY location <-> point '(-74.013, 40.711)' LIMIT 10;
```

**Note:** The point first element is longitude and the second element is latitude.

For more info check this [Query Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gist-builtin-opclasses.html#GIST-BUILTIN-OPCLASSES-TABLE).

Answer (score 3):

For completeness: you can use a [composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html) column, available from PostgreSQL 11.

To create the column:

```
CREATE TYPE geo AS (lat float, long float);
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN location geo;
```

To insert data (options):

```
-- with field names
INSERT INTO your_table (location.lat, location.long) VALUES (8.12345, -55.34567);

-- string syntax
INSERT INTO your_table (location) VALUES ('(8.12345, -55.34567)');

-- ROW() keyword
INSERT INTO your_table (location) VALUES (ROW(8.12345, -55.34567));

-- ROW() keyword is optional for multi-column composite types
INSERT INTO your_table (location) VALUES ((8.12345, -55.34567));
```

Composite types are often undesirable as they are like an unnecessary "table in a table". But in this case, I would argue they offer (slight) advantages:

- You can encode your geolocation in a single column like with [`point`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html#id-1.5.7.16.5), but with the additional advantage that you can choose the component datatypes depending on the needed precision (`real`, `float`, `numeric`).
- You can use the usual "lat, long" ordering of coordinates; when using [`point`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html#id-1.5.7.16.5) for geolocation values, you would rather go with "long, lat" for conformity with PostgreSQL practice, where several functions expect that:

  > "Points are taken as (longitude, latitude) and not vice versa because longitude is closer to the intuitive idea of x-axis and latitude to y-axis."
  >
  > ([PostgreSQL 15 Manual, on Point-Based Earth Distances](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/earthdistance.html#id-1.11.7.24.8))
- Ability to reference fieldnames in `INSERT` statements, avoiding any confusion if the format is (lat, long) or (long, lat).
- No dependency on heavyweight PostGIS, while the [earthdistance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/earthdistance.html) module, specifically the operator `<@>` for "Point-Based Earth Distances", can still be used to do proximity search. (You'll have to create [`point`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html#id-1.5.7.16.5) values on the fly though as we use a different data type and have reversed the component order to (lat, long)).