# insert jsonb data in postgresql, option array or objects, valid way

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have this update, i've read postgresql documentation, but nothing clear about how to insert data, some tutorials options:

```
1.with '{}'
2.with {}
3.with '[]'  <-- array of objects
```

and most dont' use '::jsonb' like is indicated on:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html

here my code:

```
 UPDATE customer set phones ='{  {"type": "mobile", "phone": "001001"} ,
{"type": "fix", "phone": "002002"}  }'::jsonb  
  where id ='4ca27243-6a55-4855-b0e6-d6e1d957f289';
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: UPDATE customer set phones ='{  {"type": "mobile", "phone": ...
                                    ^
DETAIL:  Expected string or "}", but found "{".
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {  {...
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 29
```

I need just record a lit of phones, need to enclose in a big name object like?  I mean for javascript , array of objets is not an object, but i dont know if that is accepted in jsonb of postresql

{ phones:[ {"type": "mobile", "phone": "001001"} ,
    {"type": "fix", "phone": "002002"} ] }

Answer (score 52, accepted):

#### Example 1 (object):

```
CREATE TABLE customer {
  contact JSONB
}
```

```
update customer
set contact = '{ "phones":[ {"type": "mobile", "phone": "001001"} , {"type": "fix", "phone": "002002"} ] }'
where id = '4ca27243-6a55-4855-b0e6-d6e1d957f289';
```

#### Example 2 (array):

```
CREATE TABLE customer {
  phones JSONB
}
```

```
update customer
set phones = '[ {"type": "mobile", "phone": "001001"} , {"type": "fix", "phone": "002002"} ]'
where id = '4ca27243-6a55-4855-b0e6-d6e1d957f289';
```

#### Notes:

1. My PostgreSQL version

```
select version();

PostgreSQL 11.2 (Debian 11.2-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit
```

2. Be sure to enclose the keys and values with double quotes.

Comment: Perfect Answer.  can you please tell me how to store point(longitude, latitude) in PostgreSQL

Comment: @IrshadKhan PostGIS might be your answer, which is a Spatial and Geographic Objects for PostgreSQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150721/which-data-type-for-latitude-and-longitude

Answer (score 7):

`'{}'` is array type in postgres. if you use `jsonb`, use regular `'[]'` for array:

```
so=# select jsonb_pretty('{"phones":[ {"type": "mobile", "phone": "001001"} , {"type": "fix", "phone": "002002"} ] }');
jsonb_pretty
{
    "phones": [
        {
            "type": "mobile",
            "phone": "001001"
        },
        {
            "type": "fix",
            "phone": "002002"
        }
    ]
}
(1 row)
Time: 0.486 ms
```

or:

```
so=# select jsonb_pretty('[ {"type": "mobile", "phone": "001001"} , {"type": "fix", "phone": "002002"} ]');
jsonb_pretty
[
    {
        "type": "mobile",
        "phone": "001001"
    },
    {
        "type": "fix",
        "phone": "002002"
    }
]
(1 row)
```