# Which data type have to use for latitude and longitude in PostgreSQL?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, latitude-longitude

I am new in PostgreSQL and I am working in Laravel project where I have to store latitude, longitude for users. And after that I have to find their friends from location so which datatype I have to use to store latitude & longitude in PostgreSQL?

Any Idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which data type for latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150721/which-data-type-for-latitude-and-longitude)

Comment: Answer for your question is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150721/which-data-type-for-latitude-and-longitude) on stackvoerflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float` or `double precision` for saving the lat and lng in PostgresSQL.