# How to store Geometry Point in Postgres using spring boot JPA?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

To store longitude and latitude as geometry location as Point in Postgres using spring boot jpa.

After applying below code it throws: column "location" is of type point but expression is of type bytea.

Also when fetching data it throws:
could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

Add dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
    <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Add column in entity class.

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "POINT")
private Point location;
```

For storing data into database

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();

            Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate();
            coordinate.x = 2;
            coordinate.y = 5;

            Point myPoint = geometryFactory.createPoint(coordinate);
            user.setLocation(myPoint);
```

I need to store data as (30.5,53.123) format in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

To add an extension of postgis in Postgresql. Add extension in particular schema as per below query.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

And change hibernate dialect with spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150721/which-data-type-for-latitude-and-longitude), you can use `point` data type to store latitude and longitude values. This data type combines (x,y) which can be latitude, longitude. If you want more precision, you can add two columns of type `float` or `double precision`.

You can also use PostGIS, which gives you addition data types `geometry` and `geography`. These data types occupy one column of 32 bytes for a point. You can refer to [PostGIS manual](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography)