# could not determine data type of parameter $1 (geometry)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, geometry, nestjs, postgis

##### CASE A

```
SELECT ST_DistanceSphere(
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(127.058923 37.242621)', 4326), "geometryType")as distance FROM "MyTable"
WHERE ST_DistanceSphere(
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(127.058923 37.242621)', 4326), "geometryType") < 500;
```

##### CASE B

```
SELECT ST_DistanceSphere(
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${longitude} ${latitude})', 4326), "geometryType")as distance FROM "MyTable"
WHERE ST_DistanceSphere(
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${longitude} ${latitude})', 4326), "geometryType") < 500;
```

When performing as in A, the query succeeds normally, but when performing as in B, an error of "could not determine data type of parameter $1" occurs.

PostGIS is properly installed in my database.

I've tried using both Prisma's $queryRaw and the Node package postgres, but the issue remains unresolved.

Comment: // Assuming longitude and latitude are variables containing the respective values
const longitude = 127.058923;
const latitude = 37.242621;

// Using Prisma's $queryRaw with parameterized queries
const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`
  SELECT ST_DistanceSphere(
      ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${longitude} ${latitude})', 4326),
      "geometryType"
    ) as distance
  FROM "MyTable"
  WHERE ST_DistanceSphere(
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${longitude} ${latitude})', 4326),
    "geometryType"
  ) < 500;
`;

console.log(result);

Answer (score 0):

Like the function name implies, [`ST_GeomFromText()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) takes `text` input. The first parameter needs to be a single (concatenated) string in valid format.

Either concatenate and pass a single parameter:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(127.058923 37.242621)', 4326);
```

Translates to:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(${point}, 4326);
```

**Or** let Postgres concatenate longitude & latitude for you:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(format('POINT(%s %s)', '127.058923', '37.242621'), 4326)
```

Translates to:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(format('POINT(%s %s)', ${longitude}, ${latitude}), 4326)
```

There are various ways to concatenate in Postgres:

- [String concatenation using operator "||" or format() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66555257/string-concatenation-using-operator-or-format-function/66556331#66556331)

Related:

- [Which data type for latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150721/which-data-type-for-latitude-and-longitude/8150944#8150944)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have parameters inside a string constant.

Try using

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(${longitude}, ${latitude}), 4326)
```